# Embedded KairosDB for tests

Tags: java, kairosdb

I want to test my application with kairosDB, but I don't want to use external kairosDB server.

Is it possible to create embedded KairosDB (with in memory DB like H2) for tests?

Comment: Consider using a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=kairosdb&starCount=0) together with something like [TestContainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java).